# Pinch zoom in CWAC

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I am using the CWAC library and wanted to implement a few functionalities on them.viz.

1. Is Pinch zoom possible?
2. I am using the camera as a part of the view pager and I am overriding `setUserVisibleHint()` to pause and resume the `CameraView` to reduce the memory footprint.Is there a better way of doing this?
3. Can touch to focus be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

> Is Pinch zoom possible?

Not via the library.

> Is there a better way of doing this?

I have never tried this.

Your need for a camera would seem to well exceed my objectives for the library (and its eventual replacement). Quoting the documentation:

> ## Library Objectives
>
> The #1 objective of this library is maximum compatibility with hardware. As such, this library will not be suitable for all use cases.
>
> The targeted use case is an app that might otherwise have relied upon ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, but needs greater reliablilty and somewhat greater control (e.g., capture images directly to internal storage).
>
> If you are trying to write "a camera app" — an app whose primary job is to take pictures — this library may be unsuitable for you.

I'll even go so far as to say: if camera functionality is more than 1% of the value of your app, do not use my libraries. Use the camera APIs directly.

Comment: I am using a ViewPager to switch between camera view and gallery view.Not writing a camera app here.I read your warnings quite well :).So if there is no way available via the library,do you have a possible solution which I could implement?without it being a library abstraction?

Comment: The camera is used just to click a picture or use the gallery to select a picture.That is all the functionalit that I am implementing.I also added a third point in the question,please let me know if that is possible too.

Comment: @Droidekas: The library does not support touch to focus.

Comment: also, any expected period on the release of the rewritten library?

Comment: @Droidekas: No. I'm working on it, but it is slow work.

Comment: Looking forward to it.Thanks for the current lib.Its a life saviour!